# Need form to call function and use AJAX XMLHttpRequest

Tags: html, ajax, forms

I have built a form that is looking for the user to enter there student id and then have it look it up on the site and then return who owns the id.  But I keep getting an error in my ajax request and it doesn't return anything from the site.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<body>

</header>
<form>
<form  id="frm1" action= "#" method="#">
<div id="userData"></div>
StarID:<input type="text" name="starIds" id=starId>

<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="getUser()">
</form>
</body>
```

```
function getUser() {
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("starId").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://cst.ridgewater.edu/Tools/AJAX_HTML   /?StarID=StarIDvalue", true);
xmlhttp.send("StarIDvalue"); 

}
```

I want to call the getUser function when submitting the form to be able to the StarID value from the website.  But now I get this when I try to get the program to work: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://cst.ridgewater.edu/Tools/AJAX_HTML/?StarID=StarIDvalue. (Reason: CORS request failed).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your site doesn't have permission to make that AJAX request. The remote server is rejecting your request because it doesn't come from the same domain — i.e., your site is not hosted on `cst.ridgewater.edu` or similar.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Answer (score -1):

You might need to edit the HTML. There's a dangling `head` tail and a couple of starting `form` tags.

Comment: Whoever voted this down, be brave enough to prove me wrong, granted that there is not an ending `head` but a `header`. I still see a useless `form` tag open.